# ASP.NET MVC 4.5.1 RedirectToAction 500 Error only after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple MVC 4.5.1 website.  When I run locally and publish to our test server, the return RedirectToAction to another controller's page works fine.  After publishing to the production server, the actual site throws a 500 error. If I go directly to the controller's view, it works fine. It's just the RedirectToAction (also tried return Redirect() and it shows same error when published). Any recommendations?  Every RedirectToAction to many different areas is now failing in production.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: What's the error description?

Comment: 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: Just as a follow up, it seems that the entire site is working correctly.  Only the compiled-in redirects are being "blocked" somehow.

Comment: Do you have logging and can confirm it is the actual redirect to action and not something happening prior?

Comment: use `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` to see real error description

Comment: In my web.config, I added these: <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" /> in system.webServer.  In system.web I added <customErrors mode="Off" />. Strangely, I still get the same 500 message.

Comment: In the event logs it doesn't show an error. In the logging for the site in IIS, it gives the same 500 error message.

Comment: Here are strange results from testing this out.  I rebuild the site and add a "test" controller.  It works when published using the RedirectToAction to the same page.  I deleted the original controller that i actually needed. Rebuild->Publish. I recreate the controller->add same redirect from test controller->Publish->500 error.

Comment: So no solution has yet been found but renaming the controllers "fixed" the issue.  I will not mark this as a fix but it's a [crappy] workaround.